# What is the effect of EMF on magnetism?

Tags: electromagnetism

Although this Q&A describes the potential effect of EMF on magnets, my question is how big is the field of a magnet (one small enough to wear as a piece of jewelry). Some people claim that magnetic jewelry can affect joints and relieve arthritis.

https://physics.stackexchange.com/search?q=does+magnetism+affect+radar

Comment: Welcome to [Physics.SE]!  The second part of your question (about affecting joints & arthritis) is a question of biology, not physics;  I have edited your question to remove it.  It would probably be better asked at [Biology.SE] or [Medicalsciences.SE].  From everything I've heard about such devices, though, the answer is "no".

Comment: In particular, you might want to take a look at [this link.](https://quackwatch.org/consumer-education/QA/magnet/)